# In a hidden Markov model, how do all observations and one state give you all states?

Tags: self-study, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

$Y^n$ are the observations of our HMM, where $Y_i=a_i$ is a single observation, where $a_i \epsilon \{0,1\}$. For example, $Y^n = k^n$ where $k^n=\{0,1,1,0\}$

$X^n$ are the actual states of our HMM, of which we know some (any) $X_i$.

How can I both 1.intuitively and 2.carefully (using actual math) reason about the following fact: If we have $Y^n = k^n$ where $k^n=\{0,1,1,0\}$ and **any** $X_i$ then we know the entire $X^n$.

I think it has something to do with the Markov implication that

> Conditioned on the present, the past and the future are independent

but I'm not very clear on how to proceed.